# Weird cout behaviour

Tags: c++, string

I noticed a rather strange behaviour when using `std::cout` for outputting something to the console.
I wrote two functions `string& toUpper(std::string &str)` and `string& toLower(std::string &str)` which should do exactly what they are called after: Convert a string all uppercase or all lowercase.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string& toLower(string &str)
{
    for(char &c : str)
        c = tolower(c);

    return str;
}

string& toUpper(string &str)
{
    for(auto &c : str)
        c = toupper(c);

    return str;
}
```

Now I tested both functions independently and they are working as expected. Then I chained both of them in a `cout` call:

```
string str = "Hello World";
cout << toLower(str) << endl << toUpper(str) << endl;
```

I expected the output to be

```
hello world
HELLO WORLD
```

but instead I just got

```
hello world
hello world
```

I tested the same using `printf` because I thought it might be something specific to `cout`'s way of doing stuff but I got the same result, so I guess I got something wrong with my code.
What's the problem with my code?

Comment: Return a copy instead of a reference and it'll work

Comment: I know that copying would work but I want to manipulate the actual string inplace.

Comment: Well you are manipulating the same string twice. Cout is buffered, so I am guessing that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: So given that `cout` line, which function will be called at what time?  I'll let you answer your own question.

Comment: The printf example is easier to reason about. Given a function `f(x, y)`, when you call it both arguments are evaluated first. Since your functions take and return by reference, it so happens that the last function "wins".

Comment: If you want to manipulate the string in place, make your functions return void and then do `toLower(str); cout << str << endl; toUpper(str); cout << str << endl;`

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calls to `operator<<` must happen in order, left-to-right, but the C++ standard does not specify the order of evaluation of sub-expressions within the statement.

The compiler can decide in which order to evaluate the sub-expressions, so that any of these outcomes is valid:

```
auto&& arg1 = toLower(str);
auto&& arg2 = toUpper(str);
cout << arg1 << endl << arg2 << endl;
```

Or:

```
auto&& arg1 = toUpper(str);
auto&& arg2 = toLower(str);
cout << arg2 << endl << arg1 << endl;
```

Or:

```
auto&& arg1 = toUpper(str);
auto&& arg2 = (cout << arg1);
auto&& arg3 = toUpper(str);
arg2 << endl << arg3 << endl;
```

Or several other possibilities. Of these three possible sequencings, only the last one would produce the result you expect. The first case would result in "HELLO WORLD" being printed twice, and the second case is the result you get with your compiler. All are valid outcomes according to the C++ standard.

Comment: Thanks for the detailled explanation and some background information. Indeed I expected the third solution to happen. Too bad that there is no defined behaviour specified for this situation.

Answer (score 4):

You are modifying a variable (the string) within the evaluation of an expression, and are relying on it being used at certain points during that evaluation.  As you have found, you can't rely on that.

One solution would be to use different strings; another would be to break up the expression:

```
cout << toLower(str) << endl;
cout << toUpper(str) << endl;
```

Comment: not only can you not *rely* on it, it's plainly *undefined behavior*. just like `i = i++` is.

Comment: @Ven: Isn't not being able to rely on a particular behavior what it means to be undefined?

Comment: nope. evaluation order is undefined – in `a(b(), c())`, you can't rely on `b()` running before `c()`, but there's no undefined behavior there. Also could be impl-defined behavior.

Comment: @Ven, no, evaluation order is unspecified, **not** undefined, and there is nothing undefined here, one function call is sequenced before the other, so it's not the same as `i = i++`. It is unspecified which is sequenced before the other, but still nothing undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Its the way c++ parses your statement:

```
cout << toLower(str) << endl << toUpper(str) << endl; //str = Hello World
```

1st step evaluate toUpper:

```
cout << toLower(str) << endl << str << endl;//str = HELLO WORLD
```

2nd step evaluate toLower:

```
cout << str << endl << str << endl;//str = hello world
```

3rd step evaluate cout:

```
cout <<"hello world\nhello world\n";
```

The reason your cout produces this result is because it is modifing  the same string before printing. Use a copy instead of a reference to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is "when it is calling the function" and how the reference is being processed. As it is a buffered stream, it seems to be calling them possibly out of order. If you remove the reference for the returned string (So you are returning a new unique string for each function) the code works properly.

```
void toLower(string &str)
{
    for(char &c : str)
        c = tolower(c);

    return str;
}

void toUpper(string &str)
{
    for(auto &c : str)
        c = toupper(c);
}
```

Comment: minus 1 – you're returning a copy after you modified the string. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with buffering at all. The function calls that modify the string are both evaluated before any writes to the stream.